# BZflag Doesn't start on Kubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, games

I've been running BZflag for quite a while but now I am not able to start it up.  Here is the error message I get:

```
mark@mark-TP300:~$ bzflag
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (XFree86-VidModeExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  10 (XF86VidModeSwitchToMode)
  Value in failed request:  0x17a
  Serial number of failed request:  156
  Current serial number in output stream:  158
mark@mark-TP300:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the resolution to 1366x768 fixed the problem.